# Redirect to Mobile app from facebook and twitter app

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

My Android app can share links via Twitter or Facebook.

If someone clicks on a link that was shared and they already have the app installed, how can I make the app launch directly?

Updated -
Simple Issue Fixed from here -
[Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)

Comment: please use full stops and commas correctly

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `<Intent-filter>` under `<activity>` tag in `manifest.xml` file like

```
 <activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When another application tries to share any of these things by constructing an intent and passing it to **startActivity()**, your application will be listed as an option in the intent chooser.

If the user selects your application, the corresponding activity (`.ui.MyActivity` in the example above) will be started. It is then up to you to handle the content appropriately within your code and UI.

And go to this for better understanding: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: How will it know what URLs to launch for?

Answer (score 0):

## Facebbok/twitter

**facebook**

```
After facebbok login  OnComplete() is called. So, fire your intent in this method.
 public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
 {
    # fire desired intent      
  }
```

**twitter**

```
 put this code into your manifest file with activity name and on which activity 
  want to redirect put the below line so link is created and you will redirect
  <activity
        android:name="com.example.mainactivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="home"
                android:scheme="oauth" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

*********************************************************************
<h6>put this into your mainactivty</h6>
static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://home";
static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://home";
```