# Open native google maps from cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, google-maps, cordova

The front end of the app is angularjs and I would like to open a native google maps application when the user clicks the following link.

```
<a class="google-map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=sydney&daddr=melbourne">Navigate</a>
```

The link opens maps in a mobile browser but I want to open native google maps.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi,check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app

Comment: Not sure how that thread is helpful? I am not trying to create a custom scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plug-in for IOS and Android that allows to call native Google maps:

https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin

Comment: This is only ios specific. I would like something that will work both on iOS and android

Comment: Added... Not so correct because ask user selection.

Comment: Changed by the plugin way. I think this is the best approach.

Comment: I am reluctant to use this approach because it may make my app slower. But as it looks like the only way I will accept this as an answer. Thanks