# Hyperlinks with non HTTP schema in GMAIL

Tags: android, hyperlink, gmail

So I'm making mobile apps and want to do links to activate things in both iOS and Android using the same URL. I know how to do this already. my intent on android is something like :

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:host="activity.action android:scheme="myapp"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

My problem is when I go to test this and want to do a hyperlink in an email myapp://activity.action is not recognized as a url in gmail on android and displays as plain text. is there a way to fix this? how do i get non standard schema recognized by gmail as a link?

Comment: Have you tried a html email with a href?

Comment: yep adding something like <a href="myapp://activity.action">test text please</a> still gets stripped out and all you get is the text

Comment: Gmail has a URL scheme protection. The same goes for many websites. I suggest you create a webpage on a server that redirects the user to your protocol and send that page to your users through Gmail.

Comment: You don't need to send the user to a webpage that redirects them to a custom scheme. If you own a domain, you can create an intent filter for a specific URLs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Custom schemes are not supported by gmail and chrome apps.  Don't do this. Follow android guidelines for opening app from browser / link. See the following post  [Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3469908/1335921)

Comment: Is there anywhere that this limitation of gmail/chrome/etc is officially documented?

Answer (score 3):

You can create intent filters for HTTP and HTTPS URLs as well as URLs with custom schemes.

For example, you might set up an intent filter like so:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data 
        android:scheme="http"
        android:host="example.com"
        android:path="/my-path" />

</intent-filter>
```