# Launch Android app linking with particular url

Tags: android

Can anybody please tell me how to launch android application from  particular URL .
If i am getting this URL From mail .

Please suggest me how i can open app on particular URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228#3472228

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have a web site, and have an intent-filter for a particular URI on that web site. For example, this is what Market does to intercept URIs on its web site:

```
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="http" android:host="market.android.com"
            android:path="/search" />
    </intent-filter>
```