# Redirect returns "Object moved to"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem. When I try to redirect user to non-http URL from MVC action, it returns:

> Object moved to here.

Full response (from Fiddler):

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: myGame-app://test.somespecificdata
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcUGlvdHJcRGVza3RvcFxUYWtlc0NhcmVcVGFrZXNDYXJlXERvY3RvcnNcRWRvY3RvclxDb25zdWx0YXRpb25cMTkx?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2015 18:19:35 GMT
Content-Length: 457

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="myGame-app%3a%2f%2ftestprotocol.somespecificdata">here</a>.</h2>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Firefox"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:53098/4c9c75263d91451fa797f9041e4bd0f3/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body></html>
```

My action (with pseudo code):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Consultation(int id)
{
      //.. specific business logic
      if(IsMobile()){
          return RedirectPermanent("myGame-app://test.somespecificdata"); 
      }
      else{
          return View("AboutGame", SomeSpecificModel);
      }
}
```

The same situation is with `return Redirect()` instead of `return RedirectPermanent()`.

My main goal is to redirect a user who uses the mobile browser to URL with special protocol (not http). This special protocol (`myGame-app://`) runs my mobile app [according to this Stack discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app). How can I achieve this, without information `Object moved to here`?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The Redirect/RedirectPermanent methods add a body to the response containing the "moved here"-HTML.
If you want an "empty" response just set the response yourself:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("url", false);
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 301;
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Be aware that the rest of your logic after this will be executed, so make sure nothing else (filters etc) that might redirect the response again happens after setting this.