# Open the app from SMS link using Smartface App Studio

Tags: smartface.io

We want to open my app when user clicks on link in text SMS. And the page need to fill up with data basing on parameters in the link.

I am not getting any clue on this. Can any one help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/project/app-to-app-call/

You can use this try it

Comment: Thanks Manthan. But, this if for app to app calling. I require open an app page by sms or web links

Comment: https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/custom-url-schemes/

See this what you are going to do is deeplinking in android/ios it's possible in smartface. I have not tried it but see if this helps

Comment: Thanks Manthan. This might be the one i want. The link which you shared is explaining how to call from another app with url schema. But, do you know how we can make the url to open the app. Any Sample url?

Comment: Sorry I have not tried it but wait for @merve to help.

Comment: I hope this may help you do some changes in your url and also your app mainfest
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app

Comment: You can try to use notifications. Instead of sending sms, you can send sms to users, and when this notification is pressed you can open your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call app from SMS by configuring custom URL schemes(http://smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/custom-url-schemes). But, it is happening only from iOS.

Still we can open the app from web links from both android and iOS with these custom url scehems.

Thanks Manthan