# How to make launch of application

Tags: android, android-activity, intentfilter

I am working on one application,What i am trying to do is first user will register from my app,after successful registration,one confirmation link will get in gmail,now from that mail if user will click on confirmation link,my app should open,Is it possible? can any one help me with that?

Comment: Have a look at https://branch.io/. You will have to configure your app for deep linking,

Comment: You can do that by following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app) post.

Comment: @zionpi i already tried that answer but still not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch custom android application from android browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

Comment: @YusufK. first read question carefully and i also tried that link,

Comment: @Aditya when you send an email with confirmation link and user click the link, when you confirm user's action, redirect user to url(something like my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here) as described on http://stackoverflow.com/q/2958701/517134  may it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must do some changes your manifest. Do changes in launcher or default activity like below:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="yoursitedomain.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="www.yoursitedomain.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

BROWSABLE and data tags help you.

Comment: @Aditya can you copy link that you want open with app? and copy your manifest code here?

Comment: Your answer helped me,i change in my manifest,,it worked thanks..aceepted and +1

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can call android from `webView`.

If you can show that email in your own `webView`.

You can programmatically call Android Activity.

I was call activity, function, `dialog` from `webView`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible but the logic is a bit tricky.

Prerequisite:

- `Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)`
- Any back-end running in the `cloud`.

The idea here is to trigger the `GCM` via the link you send in the email.
When user clicks the link your web back-end should kick/trigger the `GCM`, then the `GCM` will open your app for you.