# Deep linking in Android - Chrome does not launch #intent links

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, deep-linking

I've been trying to use deep linking from a website I own to a resource inside my app. I've been reading about how things has evolved with deep linking in Android, particularly [Paul Kinlan's blog post](https://paul.kinlan.me/deep-app-linking-on-android-and-chrome/) which seems to be the most recent explanation on how things should work.

I also have read this discussion on why [custom scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3472228/697716) is a bad practice and should not be used, which made sense.

Now I decided to use the #intent link in my website to open the resource in the app when user taps on the link. For this, I used a link like this:

```
intent:#Intent;package=com.example.project;component=com.example.project/.ui.ActivityWithResource;i.res_id=80;end
```

But when I click on it, nothing happens, and I see this in the logs:

```
chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Navigation is blocked: intent:#Intent;package=com.example.project;component=com.example.project/.ui.ActivityWithResource;i.res_id=80;end", source: http://example.com/?res_id=80 (0)
```

I then read about this on [Chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents#example), which interestingly, their example was using a custom scheme, contrary to what they had argued before should not be done!

Now if I add the HTTP scheme to my intent link, like this:

```
intent://example.com/?res_id=80#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.example.project;component=com.example.project/.ui.ActivityWithResource;end
```

Then it works, because the activity has the intent-filter to handle the urls like `http://example.com/`, but why when I specify the component, it doesn't work?

Also, when I use HTTP scheme in my intent, in shows activity resolver (except android 6.0 as I do use auto-verify), but I assume if I can get my explicit intent link to work, it should directly open the resource in the app, as I already have defined the component in the intent link. right?

Maybe the only way is to use custom scheme after all?

Thanks

P.S: Here is the activity definition in my AndroidManifest. I wasn't sure if it requires `android:pathPrefix` to work or not, so I added both intent-filters

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.ActivityWithResource"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:exported="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Are you still looking for the solution ?