# Start Service in Android App from Link URL

Tags: android, android-intentservice

**I've implemented [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228#3472228) to start a specified Activity from a web browser.**

The official [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) only talk about Activity's as well.

However, the requests are growing and depending on the request, a different Activity needs to be started. I was thinking of an `IntentService` that figures out what message and based on that, starts a specified `Activity`. What is the correct way to implement this? Because I tried an `IntentService` and it doesn't get triggered:

```
public class APIService extends IntentService {

    public APIService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public APIService() {
        super("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBind: ");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBind: ");
    }
}
```

But this solution does not trigger the App anymore.

```
<service
        android:name=".services.APIService"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="qkey"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: this is because the browser calls `startActivity`, not `startService`, just make your `Activity` as a proxy that starts the target `Activity` and `finish()`es itself

Comment: @pskink Okay, I've implemented it as an Activity.