# Android - Launcher activity multiple intent filters

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter, android-launcher

I have following activity declared in manifest file
The activity is also launcher activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".DashBoard"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:path="/page"
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I open http://www.example.com/page the app doesn't launch

Please help

Comment: How exactly are you trying to start the activity with the URL? And, what happens when you do that, instead of your app launching?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser) should help

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228#3472228)  should too

Comment: @CommonsWare when I click on the link (http://www.example.com/page) it opens browser. 
It doesn't show option to open app

Comment: "when I click on the link" -- where is that link? In a Web page? In a text message? In an email? In the address bar of the browser? Somewhere else?

Comment: @CommonsWare in a text message

Comment: Try using a link in a Web page. Or, try using `adb shell am`. Perhaps there is something about your text messaging client that is causing it to bypass your `<intent-filter>`.