# How to submit a form by clicking a text?

Tags: jquery, html

I hope to submit a form when I click the `span id="ToolBarDownload"` but it seems that the `form id="myformID"` is not submitted. What's wrong? Does my code make sense? Thanks!

By the way, the text `id="ToolBarDownload"` is outside the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery1.10.2.min.js?isassets=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#ToolBarDownload").click(function() {
                if (confirm('Do you want to Download')) {
                    $("#myformID").commit();
                }
            });

            $("#myformID").submit(function(eventObj) {
                $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "myCw").attr('value', "mydata").appendTo('#myformID');
                return true;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id="myformID"></form>
        <span id="ToolBarDownload" class="ToolBarButton" style="margin-left:5px">Download</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `commit()` method in jQuery. To submit a form, use `submit()`:

```
$("#ToolBarDownload").click(function(){
    if (confirm('Do you want to Download')) {
        $("#myformID").submit();
    }
});
```

Also note that in the `submit()` handler you can provide an object to the `attr()` method to make only a single call that changes multiple attributes. `return true` is also redundant and can be removed:

```
$("#myformID").submit(function() {
    $('<input />').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        name: 'myCw',
        value: 'mydata'
    }).appendTo('#myformID');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, could you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623211/how-to-retrieve-the-array-in-server-side-using-nanohttpd-in-android-when-i-post

Comment: Glad to help. I can't help with you other problem though.