# How to make html to android app launch hyperlink?

Tags: android, html, hyperlink

I'm new in Android development.
I don't know how to create android app launch hyperlink and embed it into HTML page.
My scenario is when anyone click on this link android app will automatically launch, (app will be pre installed into the device.)

Here is the manifest code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="9" android:versionName="1.0.4" package="com.happyconz.wherelive" platformBuildVersionCode="22" platformBuildVersionName="5.1.1-1819727">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.permission.INTERNAL" />
    <permission android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.permission.INTERNAL" android:protectionLevel="signature|signatureOrSystem" />
    <application android:theme="0x7f0b0095" android:label="0x7f09028c" android:icon="0x7f02011d" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.GlobalApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:largeHeap="true">
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0b0099" android:label="0x7f09028c" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.activity.HomeActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0b0095" android:label="0x7f09028c" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.Main" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="0x7f09011e" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.about.CustomActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar" android:label="0x7f09028c" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.video.youtube.sign.LoginActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar" android:label="0x7f09028c" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.video.youtube.sign.LogoutActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0b0099" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.recode.Recorder" android:permission="com.happyconz.wherelive.permission.INTERNAL" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.action.Recorder" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0b008f" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.CertFailDialog" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:label="0x7f09025a" android:icon="0x7f020121" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.video.MyLiveListActivity" android:launchMode="standard" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:label="0x7f090259" android:icon="0x7f020121" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.video.LiveListActivity" android:launchMode="standard" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:label="0x7f09003f" android:icon="0x7f020121" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.preference.InfoActivity" android:launchMode="standard" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0b0095" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.activity.WebViewActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.video.youtube.sign.CheckAuthActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0b0095" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.video.CreateChannelActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0b0095" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.video.CreateLiveChannelActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.adv.AdEverFullScreen" android:taskAffinity="com.wherelive.pro" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.adv.AdMainFullScreen" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0b0098" android:icon="0x7f020121" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.preference.SettingActivity" android:launchMode="standard" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0b0098" android:icon="0x7f020121" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.preference.AccountSettingActivity" android:launchMode="standard" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0b0098" android:icon="0x7f020121" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.preference.ScreenSettingActivity" android:launchMode="standard" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0b0098" android:icon="0x7f020121" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.preference.LiveSettingActivity" android:launchMode="standard" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0b0098" android:icon="0x7f020121" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.preference.MoreSettingActivity" android:launchMode="standard" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:icon="0x7f020121" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.preference.SettingProActivity" android:taskAffinity="com.wherelive.pro" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:allowTaskReparenting="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.preference.SettingActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.LicenseChecker" />
        <receiver android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.recode.service.AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter android:priority="995">
                <action android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.recode.service.alarm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.receiver.AuthReceiver" android:process=":remote">
            <intent-filter android:priority="998">
                <action android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.recode.service.certification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:label="0x7f09028c" android:icon="0x7f020120" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.recode.widget.AutoboyWidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="0x7f070001" />
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.recode.service.RecorderService" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.recode.service.IRecorderService" />
                <action android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.RECORDER_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.recode.service.CertificationService" />
        <service android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.recode.widget.AutoboyWidgetService" />
        <service android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.video.youtube.streaming.StreamerService" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey" android:value="e357fa9000ab877757425745ec7b43ad971b647b" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="0x7f0e0006" />
        <activity android:theme="0x7f0b0098" android:label="0x7f090211" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.sns.SNSSettingActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="0x7f09028c" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" />
        <activity android:label="0x7f09028c" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.sns.twitter.TwitterActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="oauth" android:host="com.happyconz.wherelive.sns" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="0x7f09028c" android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.sns.twitter.TwitterProActivity" android:taskAffinity="com.wherelive.pro" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:allowTaskReparenting="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="oauth" android:host="com.happyconz.wherelive.sns.pro" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.happyconz.wherelive.sns.twitter.OAuthActivity" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="0x7f09032a" />
        <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="180b89f527bdd6961fab824c28327acefbae668c" />
        <activity android:name="com.mikepenz.aboutlibraries.ui.LibsActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What is the syntax, can you please tell me

Comment: You'll need to add some codes inside the Manifest. Since those above codes is the decompiled manifest, I think you'll have to get access to the project of that application then recompile it with new manifest. Also, Check this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app

Answer (score 0):

Or another option is;

After you found the application packagename, If the application is in the Store you can link it to the application link to Store then if it is already installed, User can hit on the 'Open' button.

**So link it to:**

```
market://search?q=pname:<package_name>
```

Or:

```
http://market.android.com/search?q=pname:<package_name>
```