# How to launch the app from SMS content (link)

Tags: android, android-manifest, launch

i need to launch my app when click on link that is received by sms or email.I mean, the person who receives the SMS simply taps on the link provided, and that launches the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch an application from another application on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Comment: you can implement of app invite using dynamic link of firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which ever Activity you want to open, when Link is clicked
Need to be use IntentFilter in Menifest like this

```
<activity
            android:name=".interacting.InteractWithApps"
            android:parentActivityName=".index.IndexActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="www.domain.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

You also need to define link schema and host

You should follow as per [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html)