# Opening Default Messaging app on Android/iOS from web URL/Button

Tags: c#, android, html, ios

this is a question and I'm looking for guidance and example really as I haven't come across any decent ones.

My aim is to launch/invoke the default Messaging app on both android and iOS platform as the title reads. For example, lets say I have a `<a>` with href attribute, and I want to prompt the user to open their Messaging app to start composing a message.

`<a href="intent:....">Message me</a>`

I have seen good post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app/3472228#3472228). But they dont provide the parameter I'm looking for, looking at the examples, I'll need the `href` attribute... Help and guidelines are appreciated!

I'm working with an ASP.NET application.

Comment: iOS does not have a URL scheme for a default messaging app. You can open the iOS message with `sms:` or whatsapps with `whatsapp:`

Comment: Hey rckoenes, thanks can you please elaborate more and give me some example?

Comment: `smsto:...` (where `...` is the destination SMS number) should work on Android.