# Redirection from website to react-native app

Tags: react-native, redirect

I want to redirect to react-native app from website. I want to add redirection url but don't know how to do . I have added code into AndroidMainfest.xml:-

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="exampleapp"
            android:host="greetings"
            android:pathPrefix="/" />
    </intent-filter>
```

but don't know what to add in php file to redirect into app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)

Comment: Actually I am using this
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/api/v1/view"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter> 
this is not taking app as a example.com . actually app is on my local system.

Comment: when i am click on this 
<a href="intent://example.com/api/v1/view#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.app;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;component=com.app.yourActivityname;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end"> click</a>
its redirecting on Play store

Comment: not redirecting on my app

Comment: same problem with me

Comment: i am also using this