# How to send data via WhatsApp using android app?

Tags: android, whatsapp

Upon clicking some `view` in my app, How to send data via Whatsapp.

If WhatsApp is installed, it should be opened or else Google Play Store should be opened to facilitate WhatsApp installation.

Comment: Explain your problem in detail. As such it is not understandable.

Comment: I am sharing link about product through whatsup alreay installed app in device needs to open app or will open google playstore

Comment: Please check if my edit states your problem correctly.

Comment: Hi Abhi, i was shared link through whatsup, while click on the link it navigates to other app how can write ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you're looking for.

[Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

Check this link for info.

The implementation of this is very easy, you can even get Intent type in your activity, using this:

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
Uri data = mIntent.getData();

// Figure out what to do based on the intent type
if (mIntent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1) {
    // Handle intents with image data ...
} else if (mIntent.getType().equals("text/plain")) {
    // Handle intents with text ...
}
```

Also, do some research on Google before posting a question, these things are answered before.

Comment: Hi Harsh, After sharing link while click on that link its navigate to other app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app