# Is there something similar to iOS's canOpenURL to check URL schemes for mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-website

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Safari: check if URL scheme is supported in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627916/iphone-safari-check-if-url-scheme-is-supported-in-javascript)

I'm using [pic2shop](http://www.pic2shop.com/developers.html) to provide barcode scanning for a mobile web app. For iOS, one can check [canOpenURL] to see if a particular scheme is valid (tel://, pic2shop://). Is there anything in mobile browsers (iOS, Android, etc) that provides the same functionality?

Comment: I've noticed that a similar question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627916/iphone-safari-check-if-url-scheme-is-supported-in-javascript . Is this still the case or has Mobile Safari changed?

Answer (score 1):

You may try placing that URL in an `iframe` and wait for some seconds. If you are not being redirected to an app, it means that it's not registered.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  alert('It seems that your device does not support our feature.');
}, 1000);

document.write('<iframe style="border:none; width:1px; height:1px;" src="pic2shop://"></iframe>');
```

Comment: Note that if this fails it shows alert with the message "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid."