# invoking ios installed app from safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I want to invoke a ios application from browser. If the app is installed, it should redirect to the app. Otherwise, it should continue in the browser it self, with out showing an error pop up message.
I tried setTimeOut() in javascript, it not working.

Help me please...

Answer (score 1):

check here [How to register a custom app opening URL scheme with Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201724/how-to-register-a-custom-app-opening-url-scheme-with-xcode-4)

register a URI to your app, then you can open it via javascript in mobile safari

Comment: I already did it. But, while invoking the application with window.location = "myapp://",  if app is not installed, it is throwing me an error. How to handle that.

Comment: Here is the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709251/url-scheme-for-app-which-is-not-installed

Comment: <script language="javascript">
    var timeout;
    function open_appstore() {
        window.location='http://itunes.com/';
    }

    function try_to_open_app() {
        timeout = setTimeout('open_appstore()', 300);
    }
</script>

<a onClick="javascript:try_to_open_app();" href="yourappurl:">App name</a>