# What is deep link and how i can create it for App Store?

Tags: ios, jakarta-ee, deep-linking

i have application with server side (on java) and mobile app for iOS.
For implementation flow invite friends to application i need to use deep link.
Flow must be following:

1. From server I send email with deep link and token
2. User open email with link and click
3. Download app from store and sign up on application with token from link.

How I can generate link with token on server for application?

Maybe it bad flow, please correct me.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no need for deep-linking concept. Please refer below 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880395/launching-app-from-sms-link-or-email-link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955798/ios-app-store-pass-parameters-in-store-download-link

Comment: @Gagan_iOS, as it is written in the third step _If it fails, you redirect the user to the app store so they can download your app._ but user must download app with a specific invite token that will be avaible during sign up

Comment: [This might be helpful](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

Comment: solved the problem by using [branch.io](https://dev.branch.io/methods-endpoints/data-export-api/guide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as 'deferred deep linking'. It's complicated to build — I don't recommend trying to do it yourself. Take a look at free services like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) or Firebase Dynamic Links.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I found the documentation to use [API](https://dev.branch.io/methods-endpoints/data-export-api/guide/), a good solution!