# How to use a single web page view to install configure an app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios4

My app needs configuration after the user installs it, which can be done using custom URL scheme.
I can use the method described here: [Launching app OR app store from Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964515/launching-app-or-app-store-from-safari/6965646#6965646) but it means the user will have to visit the URL twice or at least go back go the safari page after the installs the app, to get it configured using the customer URL scheme (on the 2nd visit the html page will detect the app is now installed).

I would like to have the user visit the html page only ONCE and have his app installed+configured.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to send parameters to the AppStore which will be injected into the app after installing?
2. Can an app perform the following actions on its first launch:

   a. Check whether it was installed from a URL (rather than just a user looking for it on the app store) by checking the last URL visited on Safari

   b. Switch to the Safari tab and have a timeout timer reload the html page?
3. Upon the app first launch go to a 2nd URL that finds out if this user used a URL to install the app (by IP? by device identifiier?)

Thanks

Comment: why dont you load the config in a webview and configure from within the app?

as apps are sandboxed there isnt any way to get the form information from safari. I'm not really sure what you want here your question isnt very clear.

Comment: thanks for your answer and let me clarify - there is only 1 link that is shared with the user. at the end of the process the app needs to be installed and configured according to the configuration in the link. If I had used a webview I wouldn't know which URL to use, as the URL is on the native browser.

Comment: I think you need upload two or more app (for every link) to App Store which have own configuration or give user opportunity for choice after install.