# iPhone URL Scheme when application is not installed

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, popup, url-scheme

I have a problem with my app url scheme and I can't figure out how to get ride of it:

- The scheme works like a charm but It get annoying when someone open the URL in Safari, I have tried various workarounds with JS but I still get the ERROR POPUP if user comes with iOS device and does not have my app installed. Any ideas?

Code:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    var timeout; 
    function open_appstore() 
    { 
       window.location='itunes.com/';;
    } 
    function try_to_open_app() 
    { 
        timeout = setTimeout('open_appstore()', 300); 
    }
</script>
<a onClick="javascript:try_to_open_app();" href="yourappurl:">App name</a>
```

Comment: This one for example, I still get the pop-up error if the device does not have my app installed   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964515/launching-app-or-app-store-from-safari/6965646#6965646