# AngularJs open iOS app custom url and fail over

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, url-scheme, deep-linking

I have a script like this and will be called when the button is clicked.

```
<button class="btn btn-main btn-lg" ng-click="openIOSApp()">Open App</button>

$scope.openIOSApp = function() {
      // url format: myapp://
      $window.location.href = $scope.assets.urls.iosAppCustomUrl + "action/signupdone?email=" + $scope.myInfo.email;
    };
```

There is a technique using timeout for failover (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6965646/772481). However, angular $timeout won't cancel automatically if the link works. What is the alternative to open app store on angular if the custom app link doesn't exist?