# iOS - How to implement deep linking in iOS to move to a Specific page not on home page?

Tags: ios, objective-c

hi everyone i am newbie in iOS 
I have an issue with me i am working on deep linking it always goes on home page but i want to move to another page rather than home page 
my code is below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation{

    if([[url host] isEqualToString:@"page"]){
        if([[url path] isEqualToString:@"/main"]){
            [self.leftPanelNavigationController setViewControllers:@[[[ZViewController alloc] init]] animated:YES];
        }
         if([[url path] isEqualToString:@"/1"]){

            [self.frontPageNavigationController pushViewController:[[ZContactUsVC alloc] init] animated:YES];
        }

        else if([[url path] isEqualToString:@"/2"]){
            [self.frontPageNavigationController pushViewController:[[ZAboutUsVC alloc] init] animated:YES];
        }

        return YES;
    }
    else{
        return NO;
    }

    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

and my URL Scheme is 'zameen' , when i type in safari browser 'zameen://page/1' it go to 1st VC but i define 'ContactUs VC' as '1'

pls help me to move to that 
thanks in advance.

Comment: please `NSLOG` your `url path` and check what is coming

Comment: path is same as that i want mean zameen://page/1

Comment: in NSlog path shows same as i want but in app , it moves to home page (1st page of app)

Answer (score 0):

Check This First is it working. Late we can workaround to have if condition for `page`. For now check this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation{

 // if([[url host] isEqualToString:@"page"]){
    if([[url lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:@"main"]){
        [self.leftPanelNavigationController setViewControllers:@[[[ZViewController alloc] init]] animated:YES];
    }
     if([[url lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:@"1"]){

        [self.frontPageNavigationController pushViewController:[[ZContactUsVC alloc] init] animated:YES];
    }

    else if([[url lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:@"2"]){
        [self.frontPageNavigationController pushViewController:[[ZAboutUsVC alloc] init] animated:YES];
    }

    return YES;
// }
// else{
//    return NO;
}

    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

Comment: rizwan://page/x1
this goes to map vc , it goes but map view not show