# How do I create a custom url scheme that will be recognized as a link?

Tags: ios, appdelegate, url-scheme

My url scheme looks like "foo://".

This works great when I type into the browser.

The application requires I send this link in an e-mail and the e-mail opens from there. How can I configure the url scheme to be recognized as a link? I tried doing `http://foo://` but of course my browser caught that.

One solution is to ping my server `http://foo.com/redirect_to_app`. If there is a way to do this with the app only I would like to know.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the URL as `foo://` in the email body, then that is all you need to do. Of course it requires that the user reads the email using the Mail app on their iOS device and the user must have your app installed on their iOS device as well.

Your `foo://` URL will mean nothing if the email is read on a non-iOS device or computer or if the user doesn't have your app installed.

This all assumes that your goal is for one user of your app to send an email to another user of your app and tapping on the link in the email will launch your app on the receiver's iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. You need to create a webpage and create redirect code(url scheme) to your app.
Check this out... [Check if URL scheme is supported in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627916/iphone-safari-check-if-url-scheme-is-supported-in-javascript/627942#627942)