# URL Scheme fallback

Tags: html, url, href, url-scheme

Is it possible to have a fallback href?

I put an URL Scheme in a website, code below:

```
<a href="tweetbot:///post?text=test">Tweet!</a>
```

This sends out a Tweet with the app Tweetbot containing "test". If people haven't installed Tweetbot, nothing will happen clicking the link. Is there a way to do a fallback to the web version of twitter and/or different apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing similar questions regarding the `tel://` URL scheme a while ago. Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible directly from a webpage, but check out **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627916/check-if-url-scheme-is-supported-in-javascript)** as it may offer some useful hacks (such as using a `setTimeout` for if the scheme isn't present - I can't confirm that they work). My personal favorite answer there is from mrahman, who uses the `Date().getTime()` method so that users who do have the App won't get the message / be redirected.

I guess if your users are going to be using the functionality frequently then you could save their choice of whether to use the app or the web version.