# iOS Smart App Banners

Tags: ios, smartbanner

Is there a way to pull properties from iOS Smart App Banners without actually rendering the banner?  I'd like to use the banner to tell me if an app is installed on the phone or not since it apparently can detect that.

Answer (score 1):

No. Apple does not expose any APIs to web pages to access the app banner (at least not any documented ones).

However, if your app supports a URL scheme, you could use one of the (slightly hacky) methods described in [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/627916/834998) to check whether you can open that URL (and hence check whether the your app is installed).