# Universal link after installing app wont open from Safari

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

Senario: User scans a QR code with a unique universal link into our app to "redeem" their code.

They scan the code which goes to a webpage with a link to download the app.

The user downloads the app.

Returns to the web page and there is a link within the page which is the same link as the QR code.

We assume tapping the (same) URL would trigger the universal link but it does not.
The universal link works fine from email or other apps (after its been installed)

How can we fix this bad UX, is there a HTML component or redirect we need to consider when tapping the basic link on the Web page. How can we make the link initiate the "deeplink" into the app now its installed. The banner at the top is displayed but its not the ideal flow.

The user cannot scan the QR code again - they must go through the download and "reopen" app in one flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Universal links do not trigger in Safari. This is intentional behavior confirmed by Apple engineers in the forums (sorry, don't have a link right now). Their reasoning: if you're already in the browser eco-system you usually do not want to be redirected to an app, but want to stay in the browser.

What you can do is have your app implement a custom URL scheme, and your web page can then [check if your custom URL scheme is supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627916/check-if-url-scheme-is-supported-in-javascript) and open it.